# When's the time to create dedicated collections in MongoDB to avoid difficult queries?

Tags: mongodb, bigdata

I am asking a question that I assume does not have a simple black and white question but the principal of which I'm asking is clear.

**Sample situation:**

Lets say I have a collection of 1 million books, and I consistently want to always pull the top 100 rated. 
Let's assume that I need to perform an aggregate function every time I perform this query which makes it a little expensive.

It is reasonable, that instead of running the query for every request (100-1000 a second), I would create a dedicated collection that only stores the top 100 books that gets updated every minute or so, thus instead of running a difficult query a 100 times every second, I only run it once a minute, and instead pull from a small collection of books that only holds the 100 books and that requires no query (just get everything).

**That is the principal I am questioning.**

- Should I create a dedicated collection for EVERY query that is often
  used?
- Should I do it only for complicated ones?
- How do I gauge which is complicated enough and which is simple enough
  to leave as is?
- Is there any guidelines for best practice in those types of
  situations?
- Is there a point where if a query runs so often and the data doesn't
  change very often that I should keep the data in the server's memory
  for direct access? Even if it's a lot of data? How much is too much?

Lastly,

- Is there a way in MongoDB to cache results?

If so, how can I tell it to fetch the cached result, and when to regenerate the cache?

**Thank you all.**

Answer (score 1):

Before getting to collection specifics, one does have to differentiate between "*real-time data*" vis-a-vis data which does **not** require immediate and real-time presenting of information. The rules for "real-time" systems are obviously much different.

Now to your example starting from the end. The cache of query results. The answer is not only for MongoDB. Data architects often use Redis, or memcached (or other cache systems) to hold all types of information. This though, obviously, is a function of how much memory is available to your system and the DB. You do not want to cripple the DB by giving your cache too much of available memory, and you do not want your cache to be useless by giving it too little.

In the book case, of 100 top ones, since it is certainly not a real time endeavor, it would make sense to cache the query and feed that cache out to requests. You could update the cache based upon a cron job *or* based upon an update flag (which you create to inform your program that the 100 have been updated) and then the system will run an `$aggregate` in the background.

Now to the first few points:

> Should I create a dedicated collection for EVERY query that is often used?

Yes and no. It depends on the amount of data which has to be searched to `$aggregate` your response. And again, it also depends upon your memory limitations and btw let me add the whole server setup in terms of speed, cores and memory. MHO - cache is much better, as it avoids reading from the data all the time.

> Should I do it only for complicated ones?
>   How do I gauge which is complicated enough and which is simple enough to leave as is?

I dont think anyone can really black and white answer to that question for your system. Is a complicated query just an `$aggregate`? Or is it `$unwind` and then a whole slew of `$group` etc. options following? this is really up to the dataset and how much information must actually be read and sifted and manipulated. It will effect your IO and, yes, again, the memory.

> Is there a point where if a query runs so often and the data doesn't change very often that I should keep the data in the server's memory for direct access? Even if it's a lot of data? How much is too much?

See answers above this is directly connected to your other questions.

Finally:

> Is there any guidelines for best practice in those types of situations?

The best you can do here is to time the procedures in your code, monitor memory usage and limits, look at the IO, study actual reads and writes on the collections.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cache to store objects. For example in Redis use Redis [Lists](https://redis.io/topics/data-types)

> Redis Lists are simply lists of strings, sorted by insertion order

Then set [expiry](https://redis.io/commands#generic) to either a [timeout](https://redis.io/commands/expire) or a [specific time](https://redis.io/commands/expireat)

Now whenever you have a miss in Redis, run the query in MongoDB and re-populate your cache. Also since cache resids in memory therefore your fetches will be extremely fast as compared to dedicated collections in MongoDB.

In addition to that, you don't have to keep have a dedicated machine, just deploy it within your application machine.